# Creating a search with Sails.js and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm wanting to create a search page in Sails.js that will search through a MongoDB.  I know how to accomplish this.  However, I was wondering if there is a way with Waterline, or any other option, to account for typos and alternate spellings.  For example.  If the MongoDB entry is "Springfield High School" how can I account for "Springfield High-School" or "Spring Field High School" etc...  I'm assuming if this is possible it's done with Waterline some way, but I haven't been able to find any good documentation (findLike()???).

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB supports full text search through [text indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/), including search string tokenization and simple language-specific stemming. See the linked page for a full description of features.